# How do I get nohup to execute [double-]quoted inner commands?

Tags: command-line, nohup

Let's say I want to run `echo` nested into `watch` nested into `nohup`.

Starting from the bottom of the stack:

```
echo test
```

No problems with that.

```
watch -n 1 'echo test'
watch -n 1 "echo test"
```

No problems with those either.

```
nohup 'watch -n 1 "echo test"'
nohup "watch -n 1 'echo test'"
```

Problems with those:

```
~$ nohup 'watch -n 1 "echo test"'
~$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’
~$ nohup: failed to run command ‘watch -n 1 "echo test"’: No such file or directory
~$ nohup "watch -n 1 'echo test'"
~$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’
~$ nohup: failed to run command ‘watch -n 1 'echo test'’: No such file or directory
```

How do I get nohup to execute [double-]quoted inner commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nohup` isn't expecting *any* quotes. It doesn't know how to deal with them.
The command you want is simply:

```
nohup watch -n 1 'echo test'
```

In this case you could even go without the inner quotes:

```
nohup watch -n 1 echo test
```

Just be conscious of how `nohup` works though. It redirects all output in quite a raw way. You won't be able to monitor the output of watch in quite the same way.

Comment: I have no words, I totally misread the source I was reading. `nohup sh -c '<command>'` is what I actually wanted. Thanks